# Restore back up from iphone 4s which i put sim card into different 4s without losing data from the new one?

Tags: iphone, restore

Here's a challenging one for you!

I have two iPhone 4S - work & personal handset respectively.

I broke the screen on my work phone, which wasn't insured so I have put the sim card from that into my personal phone. I want the data from my work phone, which was backed up via iCloud. Some of the photos didn't automatically sync from my work phone to iCloud when I swapped sim card over that I took as I had no 3G or WiFi when these photos were originally taken.

All the aforementioned data I want on my personal phone, BUT I don't want to lose photos or contacts from my personal phone.

How do I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Connect it via USB and open import the photo's on your computer. Then put back the backup from the other phone, and you're fine. And your photo's are safe on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect your personal iPhone to a computer with iTunes and manually back it up.
2. Connect your work iPhone to the same computer and manually back it up
3. Restore your personal iPhone with the backup from your work iPhone

All the data from each phone will be kept in it's own file on your computer, and you won't need to rely on iCloud/3G/WiFi to ensure the data is saved correctly.

---

## Use iTunes

You can use iTunes to back up and restore your content on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.

***Note that iTunes and iOS do not support installing backups of newer versions of iOS onto devices using earlier versions of iOS.***

#### Back Up

To back up the content on your iOS device, follow these steps:

1. Make sure your computer has the latest version of iTunes.
2. Connect your iOS device to your computer.
3. Choose File **>** Devices **>** Back up.

If you're using **iTunes 10.7** or earlier, right-click the device from the list and choose **Backup Now**.

You can also back up by syncing your iOS device with your computer. When you use iTunes to sync, backing up is the first step.

To verify that the backup finished successfully, open iTunes **Preferences** and select the **Devices** tab. You'll see the name of the device along with the date and time iTunes created the backup.

[image]

#### Restore from a backup

If you need to restore your device to resolve an issue, follow these steps:

1. Connect your iOS device to the computer that has your backup.
2. Make sure this computer has the latest version of iTunes.
3. Choose File **>** Devices **>** Restore from Back up.

If you're using iTunes 10.7 or earlier, right-click the device from the list and choose Restore from Backup.

*Source:* [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)